# How do I fix my smooth shaded model?

Tags: modeling, shadows

[image: I've been modelling this face for a while now and have been turning on smooth shading at different intervals to make sure it looks good. Recently though, I've noticed there is this weird shading under the nostrils.]
How would I fix the shading under the nostrils without adding too many sub divisions? (my computer us quite old) This model will be for a game if that information helps.

Answer (score 1):

press CTRL+N to recalculate the Normals. And it seems like you have subsurf modifier over Mirror modifier. Move Mirror modifier up